# how to add images for pivot item header

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, pivot

Am developing a simple app for learning `pivot control` in wp7.

can we add images for pivot item instead of text in header(red mark area in bellow image ).

is it possible to  add images, please suggest me

my xaml code is:

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION" Name="mainPivot">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="item1">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="/SchoolList;component/Gallery/child.jpg"/>
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="item2">
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="/SchoolList;component/Gallery/class.jpg"/>
            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

thanks in advance

[image: in marked red area can we add images]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the Idea of @toni petrina i added images to the `HeaderTemplate` to the pivot control using `data binding`. am implemented image gallery in my app using pivot with images in header template gives great look and feel

**Xaml code** is :

```
<controls:Pivot Title="Photo Gallery" Name="mainPivot" ItemsSource="{Binding PivotImages}">
        <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Name="play" Source="{Binding imgSrc}" Height="80" Width="120" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Image Name="mainImage" Source="{Binding imgSrc}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</controls:Pivot>
```

and i have created a simple `class` with one `string property` to save the `images source` and prepared a `List` and assigned to the pivot `ItemsSource` on page loaded event

```
mainPivot.ItemsSource = items; // items is the list with image sources
```

Comment: Can I provide another image for the pivot in which I can add a image which I want to show when the pivot is not showing.

Answer (score 7):

use this tip :

```
<phone:Pivot>
        <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}" /> // important
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate> 
</phone:Pivot>
```

and then set your Pivot Item header as

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="path-to-image" >
```

[image: check the screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Simply use HeaderTemplate

```
<Pivot>
    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image ... />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

May I also add that while this is generally possible, it is not recommended for the general use. Unless you need pivot functionality for something completely different. It is somewhat non intuitive.

Comment: thanks for your answer, how can i display the images (same image that added in grid ) in place of item 1, item 2 (header). the given answer is displaying one image for all pivot items (in header ) and i updated my question with xaml code